Wordpress - Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function create_function()
Our host updated PHP and caused some of our stuff to not work. I understand create_function isnt valid any longer but I am having a hard time converting this. Can someone please help?
add_filter('single_post_template', create_function(
    '$the_template',
    'foreach( (array) get_the_category() as $cat ) {
        if ( file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH . "/single-{$cat->slug}.php") )
        return TEMPLATEPATH . "/single-{$cat->slug}.php"; }
    return $the_template;' )
);


Replace create_function() with an Anonymous function

This question is similar to: Call to undefined function create_function. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You just need to create an anonymous function instead:
// uses a static function to pass $the_template to the filter.
add_filter( 'single_post_template', static function ( $the_template ) {

    // Uses a variable instead to hold the categories.
    $cats = get_the_category();

    foreach ( $cats as $cat ) :
        if ( get_template_directory() . '/single-' . $cat->slug . '.php' ) :
            return get_template_directory() . '/single-' . $cat->slug . '.php';
        endif;
    endforeach;

    return $the_template;
});


Try the following steps:

If you are using an inbuilt theme update it.
If you are using a custom theme replace the code.

In WordPress, replace create_function() with an Anonymous function as below:
add_filter('single_template', function ($single) {
    foreach((array)get_the_category() as $cat) :

        // single posts template based on category slug
        if(file_exists( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/single-' . $cat->slug . '.php'))
            $single =  get_stylesheet_directory() . '/single-' . $cat->slug . '.php';

        //else load single.php  
        elseif(file_exists( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/single.php'))
            $single =  get_stylesheet_directory() . '/single.php';

    endforeach;

    return $single;
});

For more details about create_function(), go to this link
